# Factorizarion of an algebraic expression.

Tags: polynomials

I came across an expression, $8x^3-4x+1$.
It was further factorized as $(2x-1)(4x^2+2x-1)$,i.e. They added and subtracted $4x^2$, split $-4x$  into $-2x&-2x$, took requisite common factors. But how do they think to proceed in this way, I cannot understand? I'd be glad if you help!

Comment: Divide the whole polynomial by 8(coefficient of $x^2$) and find all the factors of the constant term you get. One of them will be the zero of the polynomial. x=1/2 or x-1/2=0 or 2x-1 will be the factor. From there you have to do some rearrangements to remove the unnecessary terms you get.

Comment: One simple trick is that a factor $ax+b$ must have $a$ divide the coefficient of the highest power and $b$ divide the constant term. So in this case you check to see if $\pm1,\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{4}$ are roots. Of course, as soon as you find one, you factorise.

Comment: The leading term is $8x^3$ so **assuming integer coefficients**, the leading terms of the two factors must be $(8x)(x^2)$ or $(x)(8x^2$ or $(2x)(4x^2)$ or $(4x^2)(2x)$.  They tried each of those, saw they must be $(2x)(4x^2)$ and developed the rest from there.